# How to convert an array of dictionaries into an array of keys using react

Tags: reactjs

Given a list:

`let names = [{name: "bobby"}, {name: "sydney"}, {name: "Paul"}, {name: "Grace"}`

I want the output to be `["bobby", "sydney", "Paul", "Grace"]`

Here is what I have tried:

```
var items = Object.keys(names).map(function(i) {
  return names[i];
})

const items = Object.keys(names).map((key)=>names[key]);
this.setState({items}); 
console.log(this.state.items);
```

Comment: Can you please add what exactly output you want to convert it to?

Comment: Your result should be : ["bobby", "sydney", "Paul", "Grace"] ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
names.map(({ name }) => name)
```

```js
const names = [{
  name: "bobby"
}, {
  name: "sydney"
}, {
  name: "Paul"
}, {
  name: "Grace"
}];

const keys = names.map(({
  name
}) => name);

console.log(keys);
```

A note about react keys, they *should* be unique within the rendered siblings, i.e. they should be unique within the dataset. Names alone may not provide sufficient uniqueness.

A second note, you might not want to generate your react keys separately from where you need them, i.e. generally they are created when you are mapping JSX.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really related to React. You can do that with JavaScript, for instance using API like `map()`.

Here is an example:

```
let arr = names.map(obj => obj.name);
```